# How can I make RInno Install only the 32 bit version of R?

Tags: r, inno-setup

I'm trying to use `RInno` to install just the 32 bit version of R because only the 32 bit ODBC drivers play nice with RODBC and my 32 bit version of Office.

When I install R using `RInno` with `Include_R = TRUE`, it installs R as I would expect however my shiny app that uses RODBC is looking for the not-installed 64 bit ODBC drivers since R is defaulting to 64 bit.

When I manually install just the 32 bit version of R and run my app everything works perfectly. Is there a way to force `RInno` to include R and install just the 32 bit version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works!

```
R_flags = '/SILENT /COMPONENTS=""main,i386,translations""'
```